# Login not working in Django

Tags: django, authentication

I'm trying to login but Django is not allowing the navigation to the profile.html

This is what I have so far

views.py

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserLoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            userObj = form.cleaned_data
            print(userObj)
            username = userObj['username']
            password = userObj['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                print("in login")
                login(request)
                return render(request, 'profiles.html',  {'form': form})
            else:
                return render(request, 'login_form.html',  {'form': form})
    else:
        return render(request, 'login_form.html')
```

forms.py

```
class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        label='Username',
        max_length=32
    )
    password = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        label='Password',
        max_length=32,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput()
    )
```

Comment: django version ?

Comment: Check out the official documentary [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in)

Comment: Django version 1.11.8

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to pass the user to login function

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login as f_login
def login(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UserLoginForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                userObj = form.cleaned_data
                print(userObj)
                username = userObj['username']
                password = userObj['password']
                user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
                if user is not None:
                    print("in login")
                    f_login(request, user)
                    return render(request, 'profiles.html',  {'form': form})
                else:
                    return render(request, 'login_form.html',  {'form': form})
        else:
            return render(request, 'login_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: that throws an error, 'login(request, user)'. Saying it can only accept one parameter.

Comment: I see that, its because your view has the same name that the login, I'll edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

Check This Code I have done login Register

https://github.com/gowthamand/django-1.11.5-crud-ajax-login-register

I used Inbuilt Login